# Xcode UI Element -> View that points to another view

Tags: xcode, cocoa, user-interface

Is there a way I can make this view using Cocoa. 
[image]

Also it needs to be resizable meaning the width should be depending on the text length? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can. Look at the [NSPopover Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppKit/Reference/NSPopover_Class/).